# Presentation of the quaternion group

Tags: group-theory, quaternions, group-presentation

The quaternion group has the following presentation: 
\begin{eqnarray}
Q=\langle i,j,k|ijk^{-1},ik^{-1}j^{-1},ij^{-1}k\rangle. 
\end{eqnarray}
I have derived down $i^2=j^2=k^2$ by a proper multiplication of the words in the relation.
My question is how to get $i^4=j^4=k^4=1$.

Comment: $ij=k,\,jk=i \Rightarrow jkj=k$, but $ki=j$ so $kik^2i=k \Rightarrow k^2= i^{-2}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for the nice brief answer!